# How to read innerHTML value from php script?

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is maybe old question and already solved, but I still don't understand how to programatically by the easiest way push innerHTML value from client side to php server side. Other stackoverflow examples and documentation not still helped me to resolve my problem.

Imagine following code:

```
<html>
<body>
   <span id="aim">2</span>
   <button onclick="sendData()">TransmitData</button>
</body>
<script>
   function sendData(){
      <?php
      // naturally, this is not working
      $thisVarNeedInfoFromClient = ?>document.getElementById("aim").innerHTML<?php

      // do the database workaround here

      ?>
   }
</script>
</html>
```

What is easiest way to do it programatically please? Because I know this is hard problem as far as JS and html is on client side, but php is executed on server side, to obtain data for example from database. I am really frustrated because I was trying to do it a couple of hours, but without luck..

Concretely, when user click on button, I need to read the number and show some data connected with that number, and later for example someone with JS will change it from number 2 to 3 on client side, and I need to make another select in Database and update client side. I saw some solutions using GET and POST methods, but I would appreciate to do it, maybe easier somehow or better explanation with code please.

(thanks in advance for your help)

Comment: PHP executes, send to the client. Now javascript is executed. If you want a javascript value in PHP, make another server request by using javascript, grab the contents and update your `innerHTML`.

Comment: thats the problem.. how to programatically do it in this case?

Comment: Simplest way, [tag:jQuery] using `$.get()` Enough help is there if you use the correct keywords, mainly `ajax`.

Comment: but I afraid that when I use GET method, I will receive innerHTML from element in file on server, not changed html file on client side... because HTML file has some state, that I want to process to get to php...when I use GET method I will only read innerHTML values from default file .. or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes and no, make a get request to a seperate php file accepting and returning specific data.

Comment: I see.. maybe, you know, I would only need some local storage for php as in JS exist ... or some global variables like $GLOBALS['var'] to hold the same value as in innerHTML tag and this will change every time when JS will change... but I did not found some global php variables or storage to remember setted variables from one JS function where PHP was used to another JS function with PHP ...